# What's the difference in the way Lua and LuaJIT process the code?

Tags: lua, interpreter, jit, luajit

From what I understood, the standard Lua interpreter first compiles the input code to "bytecode" (the output of `luac`) and then "interpretes" that bytecode.

But isn't that basically the definition of a JIT compiler? What does LuaJIT do then? How does it differ from the standard Lua interpreter? How can it be this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> isn't that basically the definition of a JIT compiler? What does LuaJIT do then?

It implements its own interpreter, which is often faster than the "standard" Lua interpreter and it JIT-compiles frequently visited fragments to machine instructions, which brings further performance gains, but limits the portability (as those instructions are machine/architecture-specific).

There are many more improvements and optimizations, which you can find in [Mike Pall's overview](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/58908). Also see [this page for the overall JIT discussion](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3851) and specifically [Mike Pall's comments](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3851?a=1#comment-57761) on it.

Comment: What interpreter does Lua use?

Comment: @user6245072 - Vanilla Lua uses "PUC Lua interpreter" (it is not fast, but portable)